# apache not starting in alpine image docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Apache not starting in alpine docker image. Here is my docker file

```
 FROM alpine:latest
 RUN apk update
 RUN apk upgrade
 RUN apk add bash
 RUN apk add apache2
 RUN apk add openrc
 RUN rc-update add apache2
 EXPOSE 80 443
 WORKDIR /var/www/localhost/htdocs
 COPY  index.html  /var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

I tried to manually start the Apache after logging into the running docker but not working

the error is

```
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start apache2 as networking would not start
```

Comment: You can try [this docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/alpine-apache/)

Comment: @juanlumn thanks that is working fine. I have also find the alpine version of apache from its official docker hub it is    `httpd:2.4.37-alpine`

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN \
    apk add --no-cache \
    apache2-proxy \
    apache2-ssl \
    apache2-utils \
    curl \
    git \
    logrotate \
    openssl

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

WORKDIR /var/www/localhost/htdocs
COPY  index.html  /var/www/localhost/htdocs 

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: yeh I am working on it. seems the binary path is  /usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: container is starting but exiting soon.

Comment: yes sorry its /usr/sbin/httpd on alpine. i tried to run, whats your error message ? i get `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: I see that warning, the apache is running when I manually run the command inside the container but never trying to connect on port 80  bash-4.4#  `telnet localhost 80`
**telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused**

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, you can start apache without using openrc.

Add `RUN mkdir -p /run/apache2` to your Dockerfile, apache stores httpd.pid file in this directory. Finally start apache using : `exec /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`